# Run only one applescript at a time

Tags: applescript

I,m new to applescript and trying to do the following.

I have an Apple script, which will be called by java program and does a work.

Now, I want to make sure that only one applescript runs at a given time. Means, if two class in java calls the applescript, I need to make sure one waits until the other applescript done with the work.

How do I do it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can share global variables between applescripts.
So one way to achieve your goal would be to create a global UNIX variable and a [Singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) class around it...